# Get post thumbnail in WP_Query

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

I wrote an Ajax suggest plugin and I want to get the post thumbnail, but don't know how. This is my plugin code:

```
$s = trim( stripslashes( $_GET['q'] ) );

$query_args = apply_filters( 
    'wpss_search_query_args', 
    array(
        's'           => $s,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ), 
    $s 
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->posts ) {
    $results = apply_filters( 
        'wpss_search_results', 
        wp_list_pluck( $query->posts, 'post_title' ), 
        $query 
    );
    echo join( $results, "\n" );
}
```

Comment: Read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the featured image? Use `wp_get_attachment_image` - Here is the code that I use in [my plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/thumbnail-grid/)

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :$the_query->the_post();

 $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

 $imagesize="thumbnail";

 $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, $imagesize, true);

//do something

 endwhile;
```

You can also use  `wp_get_attachment_url( $id );`